# How SSH authentication works with public key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I already knows the principal of public/private keys and i know how to connect to a server with a public key but i want to understand how SSH server knows and confirms that i'm the true person which own the public/private keys with only the public key??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> how SSH server knows and confirms that i'm the true person which own the public/private keys with only the public key??

#### In short:

There is your public key stored on server and if you present it during connection, server asks you to sign some "random data" and the server can verify using your public key, that you have the private part.

More information about public key cryptography you can read for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).